# Apply jQuery to body (background) but not Modal using Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to apply foggy.js (http://nbartlomiej.github.io/foggy/) to the back-drop of Bootstraps Modal.  This would allow me to blur every element in the background which I have completed so far but the Modal Popup is also Blurry.  So my question is how do I apply the blur to the back-drop and its child elements so the Modal isn't blurred but everything else is.

Here is my code. *Note* I have some code to start and stop Vimeo as well as start and stop the Carousel.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.close-video').on('click', function (event) {
    for (var i = 0; i < window.frames.length; i++) {
  window.frames[i].postMessage(JSON.stringify({ method: 'pause' }), '*')   //Pauses Vimeo Video
  $('#AVRS-Carousel').carousel('cycle');  //Starts Carousel
  $('body').foggy(false);   //Disables Foggy.js
}

});
$('[data-frame-index]').on('click', function (event) {
  var $span = $(event.currentTarget),
    index = $span.data('frame-index');

  window.frames[index].postMessage(JSON.stringify({ method: 'play' }), '*')  //Auto Plays Vimeo
  $('#AVRS-Carousel').carousel('pause');   //Pauses Carousel
  $('body').foggy();  //Applies Foggy.js

});
});
```

Also here is CSS for Bootstraps back-drop class for the Modal:

```
.modal-backdrop {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: @zindex-modal-background;
background-color: @modal-backdrop-bg;
// Fade for backdrop
&.fade { .opacity(0); }
&.in { .opacity(@modal-backdrop-opacity); }
filter: blur(5px)
}
```

Thank you for your time in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found no way to remove the blur effect from child elements. In the end I applied the blur to nav and section elements and kept modals outside of them. Bootstraps [documentation for modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) also  warns about markup placement, saying:

> Always try to place a modal's HTML code in a top-level position in your document to avoid other components affecting the modal's appearance and/or functionality.

So the HTML ends up looking something like this:

```
<body>
  <nav>...</nav>
  <div class="modal">...</div>
  <section>...</section>
</body>
```

Javascript (using bootstraps data-toggle attribute on a button):

```
$('button[data-toggle]').on('click', function (event) {
  $('nav, section').foggy();
});
```

I hope this was somewhat helpful.

Comment: Hi Trolle, this does make sense and good points.  Thank you I will give it try.